# IDEA doesn't show documentation, while working with Maven project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, ide

When I'm working with Maven project and press `Ctrl + Q`, IDEA doesn't show documentation. It should be like this (without Maven):

[image]

But IDEA shows only this:

[image]

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://superuser.com/questions/667298/can-intellij-be-set-to-automatically-download-sources-and-documentation

Comment: Download sources and everything will work (if they're available)

Comment: @EngineerDollery If only it were that simple... I have set Maven to download the source code and documentation, but it didn't help, although Maven is really downloaded all that was required.

Comment: @Jens Unfortunately, did not help.